# Unable to execute the update query in java servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I am doing Change password i need to update the old password. based on old password i need to get record and then updating record but here is the problem when i got record i trying to update it shows null in message

My code:

```
public String ResetPwd(String NewPwd, String name,String oldpwd)
     {
         String Pass="Select * from Users where Password='"+oldpwd+"' and UserId='"+name+"'";
         String UpdateQuery="update Users set Password='"+NewPwd+"' where UserId='"+name+"'";
         try{
             currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
             st=currentCon.createStatement();           
             rs = st.executeQuery(Pass);
             if(rs.next())
            {           
                PreparedStatement ps=currentCon.prepareStatement(UpdateQuery);                  
                int i=ps.executeUpdate();
                ps.close();         

                if(i>=1)
                {
                    msg="Password Changed Successfully";
                }   
            }
             else{
                 msg="Old Password Not Match Please Enter Correct Password..!"; 
                return msg;
             }
            }catch(Exception ex){}
            return msg;
     }
```

Comment: You just deleted your last question and then reposted... why?  Oh, and you still haven't added an `e.printStackTrace()` inside of your `catch` block....  Might wanna do that, there is a lot of important information one can draw from a simple stack trace js

Comment: Why do you perform 2 executeUpdate commands? The second is launched after a ps.close(), that will not work.

Answer (score 1):

`msg` is null because probably some exception is being thrown and it doesn't get set to anything. As @CraigR8806 said don't just ignore the exceptions you catch but print them at least.

The exception being raised is probably `SQLException` since you are calling
executeUpdate on an already closed preparedStatament in this point

```
            PreparedStatement ps=currentCon.prepareStatement(UpdateQuery);  
            ps.executeUpdate();
            ps.close();
            int i=ps.executeUpdate();
            ps.close();
```

Since there is no reason for a second update change it to:

```
   PreparedStatement ps=currentCon.prepareStatement(UpdateQuery);  
    int i=ps.executeUpdate();
    ps.close();
```

as a side note use try with resources as it helps with closing those resources

Comment: hi, @Zeromus, I tried with your code also still i am getting same msg is null

Comment: as i said: change  }catch(Exception ex){} to  }catch(Exception ex){System.out.println(ex);} to at least know what's going on.
Then edit your question with the error message

Comment: Thank you for giving idea i am a newer to this java platform i ma getting error `Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.` In my data base password data type is varbinary data